# Broken lights with the normal map shader

Tags: three.js, lighting

I've been trying to use the `THREE.ShaderUtils.lib["normal"]` normal mapping shader, but the lights are broken. The normal mapping itself works, but the lights appear to move crazily into weird positions when I look around or move the camera. Regular `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` works. See pics below for illustration of the problem (the yellow circles are the actual positions of the lights).

*Phong material works as expected:*
[image: Phong material works as expected]

*Normal map shader breaks things - you can see how the light is no longer emitted from the lights' real position, but rather from somewhere random (those apparently random light places also move when viewport is moved):*
[image: Normal map shader breaks things]

The geometry generation part is taken from the [minecraft example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html#L115) (with `geometry.computeTangents()` added) and the normal map material generation from the [normal map example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap.html#L156).

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally worked around this problem by using the r51dev version which has normalmapping in the phong material, but seems the dev branch has now also fixed the original normal map shader, most likely with [this commit](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/0faca8f468b7f9f701f82f9601b1e57ba421ce64).